# Flash IOS URL Request

Tags: ios, flash, air

I am making a flash app on i-pad and it all works except for the URL request.  When I run it on the local host it works fine but when I run the i-pad version the url request just does not happen, I was told it could be related to permissions in the xml document but I can't find anything online that refers to it, here is the relevant part of my xml document

```
<iPhone> 
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[ 

        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
        <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>  
        <true/>
        <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
        <true/>

        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <!-- iPhone support -->
            <!--<string>1</string> -->
            <!-- iPad support -->
            <string>2</string>
        </array>

    ]]></InfoAdditions> 
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Thanks for any halp as always

Answer (score 0):

Okay bad question, the answer was simply that the i-pad had its internet connection turned off